# How to go next img element by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have many images in the page.i want when click on the any images,image displayed on the other large img tag(it's right work).then,i could show next image when click next button and show previous image when click prev button.i tried ,but it doesn't work properly.can anyone help me?thanks.
please see my code in the below
css code is :

```
<style>
   .slideshow {
       position: relative; 
   }
  .slideshow img {
     position: absolute;

  }
  .show{}/*complete in the future*/
</style>
```

html code is :

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" width="100" height="100" alt="first image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/287" width="100" height="100" alt="second image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/285" width="100" height="100" alt="third image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/286" width="100" height="100" alt="fourth image">
  ...
</div>

<img id="largeImage" src="#" width="200" height="200" alt="Big Image">
<button type="button" Id="prev"> Previous</button>
<button type="button" Id="next">Next</button>
```

my js code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*this function set the large img tag src attribute*/
  $('.slideshow img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#largeImage').attr({src: src});
  });

  /*Next Button*/
  $('#next').click(function() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img.show');
    var $next = ($curr.next().Lenght) ? $curr.next() : $('slideshow img').first();
    var src = $next.attr("src");
    $("#largeImage").attr({src: src});
    $curr.removeclass('show');
    $next.addclass('show');
  });

  /*Previouse Button*/
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img.show');
    var $next = ($curr.next().Lenght) ? $curr.next() : $('slideshow img').last();
    var src = $next.attr("src");
    $("#largeImage").attr({src: src});
    $curr.removeclass('show');
    $next.addclass('show');
  });

});
```

you can see in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asadihasan/e0bafbdp/3/)

Comment: There is no element having class as `show`

Comment: fiddle link is wrong ?

Comment: Updated your code .. please check this link..[ https://jsfiddle.net/e0bafbdp/6/

Comment: thanks. but it isn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// here all the images will get hide and only 1st image will be displayed
    $('.slideshow img').hide();
  $('.slideshow img:eq(0)').show();

  /*this function set the large img tag src attribute*/
  $('.slideshow img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#largeImage').attr({src: src});
  });

  /*Next Button*/
  $('#next').click(function() {
  var displayImageNumber = 0;
// Find the index of image which is visible
    $.each($('.slideshow img'),function(key,value){
            if($(value).css('display') == 'block'){
            displayImageNumber = key;
        }
    }); 
    var displayImage = '';
    $('.slideshow img:eq('+displayImageNumber+')').hide();
    if($('.slideshow img').length == (displayImageNumber + 1)){
        displayImage = $('.slideshow img:eq(0)');
    }else{
        displayImage = $('.slideshow img:eq('+parseInt(displayImageNumber+1)+')');
    }
     $(displayImage).show();
     var src = $(displayImage).attr("src");
    $('#largeImage').attr({src: src});
  });

  /*Previouse Button*/
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    $.each($('.slideshow img'),function(key,value){
            if($(value).css('display') == 'block'){
            displayImageNumber = key;
        }
    }); 
    $('.slideshow img:eq('+displayImageNumber+')').hide();
    var displayImage = '';
    if(displayImageNumber == 0){
        displayImage = $('.slideshow img:eq('+parseInt($('.slideshow img').length-1)+')');
    }else{
        displayImage = $('.slideshow img:eq('+parseInt(displayImageNumber-1)+')');
    }
    $(displayImage).show();
     var src = $(displayImage).attr("src");
    $('#largeImage').attr({src: src});
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks.your answer is my answer,but please improve it.i dont want hide images when one image large showed.thanks again.